# What is the better way to healthcheck powerdns?

Tags: docker-compose, powerdns

Somewhere on internet I saw next example for `healthcheck` inside docker-compose.yml for monitoring PowerDNS:

```
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "host", "-W", "1", "-t", "AAAA", "www.google.com", "172.22.22.23" ]
      interval: 35s
      timeout: 4s
```

But this does not work, because of next error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "host": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

What is the better command to use at `healthcheck` for PowerDNS?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose instead of creating a zone you could use `pdns_control` and its [`ping`](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/manpages/pdns_control.1.html#ping-rping) command:

> `ping`, `rping`
>
> Check if the server is still alive. Will return 'PONG' when it is. `ping` works when running inside a guardian, whereas `rping` works when running without a guardian.

So your healthcheck definition would look something like this:

```yaml
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "pdns_control", "rping"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion not is not devops best practice (i guess), but i can suggest next.

I assume that a healthy PDNS container is a container which has access to database with zones.
PDNS container apparently will not exit if connection to DB is lost.

So my suggestion is to use `pdnsutil` (cli tool which installed with pdns) to call some [commands](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/manpages/pdnsutil.1.html) to check if connection is alive.
For example, we can try to create and delete zone (which is kinda bad for DNS server)

```yaml
    healthcheck:
      test: >
        pdnsutil create-zone random.zone && pdnsutil delete-zone random.zone
        || exit 1
      interval: 60s
```

Or empty zone can be created only for healthchecking purposes - to get info about it (it should be created because Not Found zone will be considered as error)

```bash
pdnsutil create-zone healthchecking-zone-12345abc.com
```

```yaml
    healthcheck:
      test: >
        pdnsutil list-zone healthchecking-zone-12345abc.com || exit 1
      interval: 60s
```